# Is there a way to run lyx code in terminal?

Tags: lyx

Is there a way to compile lyx file in terminal?

If that helps, I want to do this because I made a lyx file with many packages, which is really slow running in lyx GUI. I wonder if there is a way to compile that in terminal just like running tex files by `texmk -xelatex xxx.tex`.

Actually I found following command in Converting LyX to LaTeX

```
$ lyx --force-overwrite --export pdflatex document.lyx
```

However, it returns me following information. I tried pdflatex and xelatex both.

> Error: Couldn't export file
>   No information for exporting the format xelatex.

Thanks in advance.

with best regards

Comment: See the linked question and the LyX wiki. You're specifying the format incorrectly. For pdfLaTeX you need to specify `pdf2` not `pdflatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I did test very line the op mentions, it worked fine on my box. Might be an older LyX though

Comment: Thank you for your answers, actually the problem happened because I run latex in a virtual machine and the .lyx file I run is in a shared folder between host sys and guest sys. Thanks for your answers though.